# How to tint a vectorial NSImage (PDF)

Tags: macos, pdf, nsimage, tint

All my images are monochrome PDF in XCAssets. I would like to color them at runtime but I can't find any tint property in NSImage.

When I use *NSRectFillUsingOperation* it rasterises the picture, so I'd rather avoid it.

In summary how can I tint vectorial NSImages using RGB without rasterising ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up setting a CIFilter called "CIFalseColor" over the button in the IB and then at runtime I control the color with :

```
button.contentFilters[0].setValue(myCIColor, forKey: "inputColor1")
```

This works if your image is white, inputColor2 controls the black, so I presume that a greyscale image would be a mix between the two.

It's not the best because it hurts the performance of the app but it will do until somebody finds a better way.

Comment: This is a nice clean way to do it, thank you. In MacOS 10.14 there is a new tintColor property on NSImageView which might be faster, if you are using those.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Core Graphics context, then you can specify the Blend Mode for overlapping objects using `CGContextSetBlendMode`. This can take values representing each of the standard Blend modes in the PDF Specification, e.g. Difference, Multiply, Overlay, Screen, etc.

Then use `CGContextFillRect` to create a tint box in the colour you want.